# HIVE:: How To Mimic SQL Server Table-Value Function

Tags: hive

I am really new to the hive space and am learning as we go.  Anyway, currently I am using a SQL Server Table function that accepts several input parameters and returns a table of dates (invoicedate,duedate).

For example, i would pass in ('2017-01-01',12,30,3) (date, duration, terms,interval) and the output would be something like:

```
'2017-01-01','2017-02-01'
'2017-04-01','2017-05-01'
'2017-09-01','2017-10-01'
'2017-10-01','2018-01-01'
```

First, is this feasible to do within the hive environment?  And second, if so, I'm thinking the UDTF would be the method.  If anyone has any thoughts or can point me to an online example they have seen, i would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Check the correctness of your example and explain its logic.

Comment: Essentially, what i'm doing in SQL server is creating a payment schedule for an invoice.  I pass in an initial date (date), how many months the invoice will run (duration), how many days before it is considered due (terms), and how often to expect a payment (interval - ie monthly, quarterly, etc).  Using these 4 values, in SQL Server, it will generate a table of dates that will be used later to calculate an aging schedule.

Comment: I still don't see how you are using "terms" here and  the example still looks wrong. It also seems there is no need for UDTF not in Hive nor in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a UDTF:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF

.................................